# Using Lion Mail.app on Snow Leopard

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, osx-lion, apple-mail

Is there any possible way to use the Lion Mail.app in Snow Leopard? I was thinking to somehow extract it from the Lion disk image, and then just put it in `/Applications` on Snow Leopard. But I'm guessing there are compatibility issues that would keep this from working. Anyone have a solid answer on this?

Comment: did you try this?

Answer (score 4):

The Lion Mail.app will make references to interface frameworks / interface elements that are not available in Snow Leopard and will either not run at all or be incredibly unstable.

With that said, I would be interested to see what happens. You could always back up the Mail.app in Snow Leopard and give the Lion version a go... it won't be the end of the world.

Based on my searches, there is no solid evidence - but you could be a source if you give it a shot.